# In vows, is there a `beforeEach` / `setup` feature?

Tags: node.js, vows

Vows has an undocumented `teardown` feature, but I cannot see any way to `setup` stuff before each test (a.k.a. `beforeEach`).

One would think it would be possible to cheat and use the `topic`, but a topic is only run once (like `teardown`), whereas I would like this to be run before each test. Can this not be done in vows?

Comment: I doubt it, have you considered using mocha instead?

Comment: Yes I've been looking at Mocha as well, but the vows syntax just seems more clean without all the nested functions. To me it seems weird not having a beforeEach/setup feature. Even weirder that I cannot find anybody asking for it. Am I totally of base here?

Comment: Vows is an old library and it isnt actively being worked on, only maintained. You can use the exports interface of mocha if you want

Comment: @Raynos Seriously? It seems pretty active when looking at the commits https://github.com/cloudhead/vows/commits/master - But if you are correct there should be some notice in the README file. I've just spend a lot of time testing out this module :(

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `topic` that does the setup, and the tests come after that. If you want it to run multiple times, create a function and have multiple topics that call that function.

It is a bit convoluted because it is not explicit, you should definitely consider [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) not only because it is actively maintained, but it makes tests easier to read than what you end up with when using vows.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. @Raynos also mentioned in his comment above that vows isn't an active project any more. What a shame :( I really liked the clean syntax. But you might be right... I should probably be moving to Mocha instead

Comment: Mocha runs test serially, which is a huge turn off (for some uses)